# how do I add JavaFX to a gradle build file using Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, javafx, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

how do I add the javafx dependencies through gradle?

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$ gradle clean

> Configure project :
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX/build.gradle.kts:13:7: Unresolved reference: openjfx

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX/build.gradle.kts' line: 13

* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 13:   org.openjfx.javafxplugin
                 ^ Unresolved reference: openjfx

1 error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$
```

the [manual](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) says:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}
```

my build file has:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    java

  org.openjfx.javafxplugin

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    application
}
```

which is generating the above error.

Comment: Did you check the plugin's [repository](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin)? There is Kotlin DSL too.

Comment: I'll update the question (the DSL syntax confuses me)

Answer (score 22):

in the `plugins`-section you have to put

```
id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.8"
```

instead of just `org.openjfx.javafxplugin`.

After that you can put a `javafx`-section like

```
javafx {
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}
```

somewhere (I prefere to put it next to the `dependency`-section). Here you can put in any module you need.

For further configuration posibilities have a look [JavaFX Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin#getting-started).

Comment: You really saved me hours headache, thanks a lot!